# Javascript: How to extract value of dynamically changing number in style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Warning: I've done ***zero*** javascript previously.

I've gotten stuck with this particular problem at work -- we have a central web interface, and in some particular pages we display tables. All tables come with a "Lock/Unlock table" button so that you can lock your screen in place.

I have the lock button do a scrollTop() to the button's top position constantly to lock the view in place even if a user tries to scroll.

eg

```
var buttonPos = button.position().top;
jQuery(window).scrollTop(buttonPos);
//have it keep doing this
```

BUT there's a slight problem.

```
<body id="body" style="padding-top: 160px;">
```

This "padding-top" value can change via our Perl scripts behind the web interface. Long story short, when it does change things get messed up.

The solution I'd like to implement is something like this retrieving that changing "padding-top" value and offsetting by that so things don't get messed up when it changes.

```
var offset = document.getElementById('body').style.paddingTop; //this would get that "padding-top" value
var buttonPos = button.position().top - offset;
jQuery(window).scrollTop(buttonPos);
```

Except this doesn't work.
When I hard code the number in for offset (eg 160, 0, whathaveyou), it works. But this doesn't work. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: where are you running this code? if you do not wait for the body to render you will get the wrong offset. What is not working exactly?

Comment: var buttonPos = button.position().top - offset; isn't working. If I do say - 160 instead of doing - offset it works for that particular case. But if I look at the values in that, <body id="body" style="padding-top: 160px;">, the padding top value changes as it is supposed to. But I can't get that value to go into offset variable for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that the value that you are fetching is a string and it has 'px' at the end. To remove this use this:

```
parseInt(buttonPos, 10);
```

Your entire script should look like this:

```
var offset = document.getElementById('body').style.paddingTop;
parseInt(offset, 10);
var buttonPos = parseInt(button.position().top, 10) - offset;
parseInt(buttonPos, 10);
$(window).scrollTop(buttonPos);
```

Comment: It's not working properly. By curiosity I did an alert(offset) right after your parseInt line and it still showed 0px, 160px, etc.  EDIT: I made another variable and assigned parseInt to that, then tried subtracting. That worked.

Comment: Hmm, question. If I refresh the page, then try clicking on the button, it doesn't work anymore. BUT, if I trigger the thing that changes the value of padding Top, then it works. Do you know what could cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following...

```
var offset = $("#body").css("padding-top");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop):

```
var buttonPos = button.offsetTop; // assuming button is the HTML element
jQuery(window).scrollTop(buttonPos);
```